# pointer-events: none is not working on contenteditable element

Tags: html, css, pointer-events

I have a parent `div` element in which the `pointer-events` is `none`. inside this `div` there's a `span` in which its `contenteditable` attribute is `true`, but I still can edit the span element content on Chrome, while the `pointer-events` for parent div is none.

But in Firefox, everything works correctly, and I cannot edit the span content.

You can find the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qn40tgkz/)

and here's my code:

```
<style>
.item-disabled{
    opacity: 0.3;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.media, .media-body, .media-heading{
    padding: 15px;
}
.list-unstyled{
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
</style>

<div class="item-disabled">
    <li class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="media-heading">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><span  contenteditable="true">Span Conetnt</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that currently chrome is unstable for the `pointer-events` element while Firefox is preferably stable.

As you can see, in the MDN documentation, Firefox is more stable and more compatible than chrome for `pointer-events`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

I would recommend to display it on Edge as it is more compatible or even use other element to replace the feature whenever possible until Chrome and Firefox is more compatible in the future